# Game renders a frame only if I alt-tab

Tags: windows, gaming, rendering

Most games run just fine, but some games only render one frame if I alt-tab away from them and then alt-tab back to them. Some other games additionally render one frame per mouse click.

Changing the games' internal settings did not help. Neither did any experiments with Windows' resolution-settings, high-dpi-scaling or enabling compatibility profiles.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs on Windows 10 (and 8?) when the user has a high-contrast theme. Switch to a regular theme and the games will render normally.

The reason has something to do with how the window manager composes/combines the windows' contents and sends them to the GPU. Windows 7 did not have this problem.

This is only a workaround, because I currently don't know of any non-high-contrast theme that does white-on-black correctly.